# Using an inoremap with `r`

Tags: insert-mode, replace

I have some `inoremap`'s in my vimrc, such as

```
inoremap \c <c-v>u2705
```

which enters a ✅ emoji for when I am writing checklists.

However, I noticed that while I am able to use it when in insert mode and in Replace mode (triggered using `R`), I am not able to call the mapping when calling `r` (when trying to replace a single character). It just ends up replacing with `\` and then triggering `c`.

Is there a reason why `r` doesn't actually switch the mode to insert/replace? Is it tied to its own special mode?

And is there a workaround to enable me to replace a single character using `r` with my `inoremap`?

Comment: Why not using an abbreviation instead (:ab \c ✅)? Incidentally, it also works in Replace mode.

Comment: @RobertSmith "it works in Replace mode" means it works when using `R`, not `r`, which is the crux of the question.

Comment: The only solution I can think of using `r` is `r<C-v>u2705`, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble You're right. I think if OP needs more than 1 character to trigger the mapping, then switching to Replace mode becomes a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Even though `r` supports lmaps and digraphs, it does not switch the Insert mode, unlike, say, `R`. And so your mapping won't be applied.

You need to get used to typing something different, for example, `s\c<esc>`.

> Is it tied to its own special mode?

The docs do not call it "a mode" specifically. This is rather "get and use a char" thing. Kind of what does `f`, `t` and such.

Comment: Is there a way to map r to do that?

Comment: @ZaidGharaybeh I don't think it's worth an effort.